# Python/PyHive - extract specific error message from exception

Tags: python, error-handling, pyhive

I'm facing an exception [similar to this one](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive/issues/53) and I'm trying to handle it based on the error itself. 
The problem is that `pyhive.exc.OperationalError` is very generic and handles errors from timeouts to non-existent tables so I would need the exact value from the `errorMessage` part in order to handle each error type differently, like if it's a timeout, wait and retry; if it's something else, handle it differently and so on.

If I catch the error as `except OperationalError as e`, how would I extract the `errorMessage` part? I *could* parse the string representation (`e.__str__()`) but that seems weird as I'm sure there's a proper way.

Comment: I am also looking for a solution for this issue. please share if you find one

Answer (score 1):

If you see the implementation [hive Exception implementation](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive/blob/master/pyhive/exc.py), It simply inherited `Exception` So it has exception details in the format of string only that looks like somewhat `json` that actually confuse us and we hope to access it using an instance variable or as a dictionary but in reality it is just string that looks like `json` .

But We can use the reguler expression to extract details as we wish like `errortype` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I found one other way to do it, That might seems a much better way.

```
 try:
        return presto.execute_query_safe(query, bind_params)
 except pyhive.exc.DatabaseError as e:
        logging.error("Query failed", exc_info=1)
        if error.args[0]['errorName'] == 'SYNTAX_ERROR' or error.args[0]['errorType'] == 'USER_ERROR':
            raise NonRecoverableQueryError('Non Recoverable Error: ' + str(error))
        raise e
```

Answer (score 0):

you can extract the errorMessage this way

```
from pyhive import hive, exc

try:
  connection = hive.connect(host="localhost", port=10000)
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute(sql_string)
except exc.Error as e:
  error_message = e.args[0].status.errorMessage
  print(error_message)
```

you can use `dir(e)` to find the methods and dunder methods for each object. which will allow you to see what methods you can call to access the data.